# Prove that $Phi$ is an isomorphism - Identification of tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $E$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space. **Prove that**:
$$\begin{array}{ccll}
\Phi:&Hom(E\times \stackrel{(r)}{\ldots} \times E,E)&\longrightarrow&\bigotimes_r^1 E\\
&\psi &\longmapsto &\Phi(\psi)
\end{array}$$
given by $\big(\Phi(\psi)\big)(u_1,\ldots,u_r,\omega)=\omega\big(\psi(u_1,\ldots,u_r)\big)$ for all $u_1,\ldots,u_r\in E$ and $\omega \in E^*$ is an **isomorphism**.

(1) In fact, the linearity of $\psi$ and $\omega$ prove that $\Phi$ is linear.

(2) Also, it is easy to show that is injective. Let $\psi_1,\psi_2\in Hom(E\times \stackrel{(r)}{\ldots}\times E,E)$ such that $\Phi(\psi_1)=\Phi(\psi_2)$. Then for all $u_1,\ldots u_r\in E$:
$$\big(\Phi(\psi_1)\big)(u_1,\ldots,u_r,\text{id}_E)=\big(\Phi(\psi_2)\big)(u_1,\ldots,u_r,\text{id}_E)\Rightarrow \psi_1(u_1,\ldots,u_r)=\psi_2(u_1,\ldots,u_r)$$
And $\psi_1$ must be equal to $\psi_2$

(3) How can I get that $\Phi$ is surjective??

Comment: Compare the dimensions. If $\Phi\colon A\to B$ is injective and $\dim A=\dim B$, then $\Phi$ is also surjective.

Comment: It's unclear to me how your definition of $\Phi(\psi)$ produces an element of the $r$-fold tensor product $E^{\otimes r}$.

Comment: In fact, the first space has dimension $r (\dim E)^2$, and the second space has dimension $(\dim E)^r$...

Comment: @AlexProvost I think $Hom(E\times \stackrel{(r)}{\ldots} \times E,E)$ is supposed to refer to the set of *multilinear* maps.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Yes, assuming that... how does his definition of $\Phi(\psi)$ produce a tensor in $E^{\otimes r}$?

Comment: @AlexProvost It says $\bigotimes_r^1E$, by which they mean ${E^*}^{\otimes r}\otimes E^{\otimes 1}$. And that in turn is defined as being the space of multilinear maps $E^r\times E^*\rightarrow k$. So $\Phi$ is defined as taking a multilinear map $\psi:E^r\rightarrow E$, and giving a map which takes $r$ vectors and a covector and gives a scalar.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Oh my, so they meant $(1,r)$-tensors. That went completely over my head.

Answer (score 1):

First note that this wouldn't be an isomorphism if $E$ was infinite-dimensional. So we have to use the fact that $E$ is finite-dimensional somewhere in the proof. The way to do this is just to verify that both sides have the same dimension $\left((\mathrm{dim}E)^{r+1}\right)$ and hence an injection between them is an isomorphism.